# Kendo Grid editable option is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have simple kendo grid code to enable edit option for selected columns. However, editable option is not working.

[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@srichatala/aSEpALaH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're setting the schema when you're creating the grid. You need to set the schema when you're creating the datasource instead.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{"EmpId":"Dev001", "Name": "David"},{"EmpId":"Dev002", "Name": "Sam"}],
    schema:{
    model:{
        id:"EmpId",
        fields:{
            EmpId:{editable:false, type:"string"},
            Name:{editable:true, type:"string"}
        }
    }
  }
});
  
$("#empGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:dataSource,
    columns:[
        {field:"EmpId"},
        {field:"Name"},
        {
            command:["edit"]
        }    
    ],
    editable:"inline"
})
```

Here is the updated [dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ixeNeXUH)